# Java Support in Kettle

Tags: kettle

Is kettle support java object mapping and transformation. Can I take java object (serialized)as input and generate some other file(like xml ) or stream after transforming some of its attribute and persist in db again and vice-versa.

Answer (score 1):

you can do whatever java allows using User defined Java Class Step.

you can import any java library in UDJC Kettle as usual in java

http://type-exit.org/adventures-with-open-source-bi/2010/10/the-user-defined-java-class-step/

Answer (score 0):

FYI, you can do this from JavaScript also since PDI's JavaScript engine is Rhino. You can access Java objects from JavaScript.